# retrieving data in iOS app (swift), JSON altered by Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, sensors

I have several sensors sending data to a company server. From that server, I am using WebHook API to push the data to my own Firebase server. I notice that the data structure is altered when it is sent from the company server to my Firebase server. The data is initially structured as follows:

```
{
"gatewayMessage":{
   "gatewayID":"111346" ,
   "gatewayName":"CGW2+Verizon+-+111346" ,
   "accountID":"8963",
   "networkID":"14979" ,
   "messageType":"0" ,
   "power":"0",
   "batteryLevel": "101" ,
   "date": "2016-05-23 15:10:29",
   "count":"1",
   "signalStrength": "30",
   "pendingChange": "False"
},
"sensorMessages":[
  {
      "sensorID":"129238" ,
      "sensorName":"Vibration+Meter+5" ,
      "applicationID":"95" ,
      "networkID":"14979" ,
      "dataMessageGUID":"0f871139-a8b2-4df9-b783-effaaa90e1d8",
      "state": "1" ,
      "messageDate": "2016-05-23 15:10:25",
      "rawData":"1.9%7c1%7c13%7c12%7c12%7c21%7c100%7c1",
      "dataType": "Speed|Speed|Speed|Frequency|Frequency|Frequency|Percentage",
      "dataValue": "1.9|1|13|12|12|21|100",
      "batteryLevel": "100",
      "signalStrength": "24",
      "pendingChange": "True"
}
]
}
```

Then, when the data is sent to Firebase and I retrieve it in Xcode using Swift it appears as follows:

```
{
"-KIT9FvatZT2wNfS3JKZ" =     {
    gatewayMessage =         {
        accountID = 8963;
        batteryLevel = 101;
        count = 4;
        date = "2016-05-23 15:08:29";
        gatewayID = 111346;
        gatewayName = "CGW2+Verizon+-+111346";
        messageType = 0;
        networkID = 14979;
        pendingChange = False;
        power = 0;
        signalStrength = 30;
    };
    sensorMessages =         (
                    {
            applicationID = 95;
            batteryLevel = 100;
            dataMessageGUID = "199c0da1-be38-4bac-a36c-c5cdb5f2ed37";
            dataType = "Speed|Speed|Speed|Frequency|Frequency|Frequency|Percentage";
            dataValue = "0|0|0|0|0|0|0";
            messageDate = "2016-05-23 15:08:25";
            networkID = 14979;
            pendingChange = True;
            rawData = "0%7c0%7c0%7c0%7c0%7c0%7c0%7c1";
            sensorID = 129238;
            sensorName = "Vibration+Meter+5";
            signalStrength = 24;
            state = 1;
        }
    );
};
```

Because of this bizarre formatting, I am unable to read in the pertinent data in Xcode. I am honestly only concerned with the "sensorMessages" child and, in particular, the "sensorID", "batteryLevel", and "dataValue" fields. If anyone could provide me with some help in only retrieving the aforementioned data it would be greatly appreciated.

Again, to reiterate, I am only trying to retrieve the "sensorMessages" data in Xcode. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Chris

I tried the following in order to access and print the "sensorID" parameter:

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://glowing-fire-3705.firebaseio.com/data")

    ref.queryOrderedByChild("sensorMessages/sensorID").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:  { snapshot in
        var sensorID = snapshot.value["sensorID"]
        print("the sensor ID is \(sensorID)")
    })
```

This results in a value of "nil" for the sensorID which, I know is not the case.

Comment: What did you try (show code) and what problem is the extra level causing you?

Comment: @Wain I have added my attempt in the prompt. I am, clearly, a beginner (just to warn you) and may need a bit of guidance